# Error typesetting large bracket with multiple lines

Tags: errors, brackets, cases

I was following a Wikibooks [section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics#Braces_spanning_multiple_lines) to create multiple lines within a single large bracket. Something like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/4/9/c/49c828f9896085fc534f4ada1f072779.png).

The problem is that when I type in the given code, which is

```
\[
 u(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   \exp{x} & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\
   1       & \text{if } x < 0
  \end{cases}
\]
```

I get the following error in my document:

```
Misplaced alignment tab character &.
```

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: You probably don't have `\usepackage{amsmath}`

Comment: include a MWE and you might get help

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, it was the missing amsmath package only! But that's not fair; why didn't I get a "not found" error in that case?

Comment: @dotslash Unfortunately, the first version of LaTeX copied the `\cases` macro from Plain TeX and it's still there for backwards compatibility. So LaTeX doesn't balk when finding `\begin{cases}` because this means doing `\cases`; but the syntax of the Plain TeX `\cases` is very different (and foreign to LaTeX), so the weird error messages.

Comment: Amazing info! What, then, is the native LaTeX syntax for `\cases`?

Answer (score 4):

The LaTeX kernel provides a `\cases` command that's literally copied from Plain TeX. This is a remnant from the olden days and it is the reason why

```
\begin{cases}
...
\end{cases}
```

without loading `amsmath` doesn't raise the `Environment cases undefined` error.

The syntax for `\cases` is really foreign to LaTeX; it must be used in math mode (inline or display) as

```
\cases{
   \exp{x} & if $x \geq 0$ \cr
   1       & if $x < 0$    \cr
}
```

Notice `\cr` for terminating the row, where `\\` wouldn't work; note also that the second column is typeset in text mode, differently from the `cases` environment of `amsmath`.

It's surely better to load `amsmath` (which also provides `\text`) and input your equation as

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

...

\[
 u(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   \exp{x} & \text{if $x \geq 0$} \\
   1       & \text{if $x < 0$}
  \end{cases}
\]
```

I always recommend reentering math mode without closing `\text`; it's more practical.